# Does the GPU render things even if the monitor is not attached?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, vnc, virtualgl

I have a Linux remote machine running Ubuntu 20.04, mounting a Geforce Titan X. When I run a Pytorch script that requires GPU power, everything seems to work (the GPU is very much active as shown in `nvidia-smi`). However, when I try to run any other application, the GPU is not doing anything. I have tried from the VNC to run the classic `glxgears` and `glxheads` and they use llvmpipe. A Unity3D scene also doesn't use any GPU capability. Rendering is slow.

This machine is quite far and someone else set it up for me. I am not sure a monitor is actually attached to it. I have assumed it is because I am connected through VNC (and I naively thought  that you need a monitor for that!).
Appaently, I don't need a monitor for using VNC, which led me to think that the GPU needs a monitor attached to it to render stuff.

So I have several questions

1. Is it true that I don't need a monitor to run VNC on a remote machine?

2. Does a GPU needs a monitor to render stuff? If a machine doesn't have a monitor, could this explain why the GPU doesn't seem to get used?
3. Which way to go to solve this? I have read that VirtualGL may be useful in my case. Is this correct?

Comment: I use VNC to connect to our home server all the time, which does not have a monitor attached.  When I *do* plug in a monitor, it acts different on VNC though - the resolution changes (increases). So there is some kind of effect from the monitor. Can't help with the other two.